Can I start an unpackaged WinUI3 app within the same process like ShowDialog() does in Windows Forms?
Currently I have process that previously started a windows forms application with myWinForms.ShowDialog() so it was running in the same process and did not created a new one for it. We have to replace our UI technology from winforms to a WinUI, so is it possible to start/display an unpackaged WinUI3 app within the same process and not starting a new process for it?
The reason why we want it like that is that we have an app (Process A) which can run extensions, like an Add-on (Process B) and we would like to avoid having another process with the WinUI app (Process C) as it could be more costly on resources. If we would start it with:
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("path_to_WinUI3_app.exe");

then it obviously would start a new process, so is there a way or workaround to avoid it?

"I have process that previously started a windows forms application with myWinForms.ShowDialog() so it was running in the same process". That's not possible. Maybe you mean that your initial process was referencing another .dll or .exe assembly and started a dialog from it?
